# Can we upload the files only by using jax-rs with out using any implementations like jersey or rest-easy

Tags: file, upload, jax-rs, using

I am trying to upload file only by using jax-rs with out using any other implementations like jersey or rest-easy

Comment: Why don't you want to use an implementation? What type of clients will be doing the uploading?

Comment: I am working on EJBs. when I am using jersey implementation I am getting EJB instance as null. Hence I am going with Jax-rs for file upload with some parameters.

Comment: Do you understrand that there is no such thing as working _just_ JAX-RS? You are _always_ using an implementation under the hood whether you know it or not. The implementation is the engine for JAX-RS to make it work. If you are using Glassfish server, then you are using Jersey. JAX-RS doesn't work without an implementation. Whatever implementation you are using, I'm sure you can just add the multipart support for that implementation and it should work.

Comment: If you tell us what server you are using and show your application configuration setup, I might be able to get you started with working with multipart.